# jQuery add - multiple selectors

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to add multiple jQuery-wrapped objects in a **single** invocation of jQuery's `add` method?

Contrived example:

```
var sel2= $("#id2");
var sel3= $("#id3");

$("#id1").add(sel2, sel3); //This code doesn't work, is something like this possible?
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var sel2= $("#id2");
$('#id1').add(sel2).add('#id3')
```

Comment: @mvdanj - its not a good practice to downvote people who are trying to help you. Please let us help you in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this without the `.add()` at all?

```
$('#id1,#id2,#id3')
```

Comment: the question is how to add multiple jQuery-wrapped objects in a single invocation

Answer (score 0):

You can by dereferencing the objects, passing them as an array:

```
$('#id1').add([ sel2[0], sel3[0] ]);
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YtRh3/6/)

Comment: That's nice :) but be carefull that `sel2[0]` will only work with a jQuery object containing only 1 element